# H2 console in memory Spring Security Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation

Tags: spring, spring-security, h2

I set all properties in application.properties. In another project without Spring Security it runs. But when I use Spring Security It shows:
I tried to ignore /h2-console in spring security but does not work.

I want to be able to connect to testdb database in memory.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2h7v.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.